# Confusion about the output of this c program

Tags: c

I am new to C programming as I have just started learning about programming. I was looking at the below program-

```
main( ) 
{ 
 printf ( 5 + "Good Morning " ) ; 
}
```

And I found out the output of the above program is `Morning`. By simple calculation it looks like, it has skipped starting 5 characters. But I am thinking why it is skipping those first five characters?

Can anybody explain me in detail about this program? Thanks for the help.

Comment: This is same as `*(arr + i)`, where `arr = "Good Morning"` and `i = 5`.

Comment: Does this compile? I think not.

Comment: @EdHeal: Looks fine other than the `main()` signature.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams - There was me thinking that to put all the warnings on! Silly I know.

Answer (score 4):

This is called pointer arithmetic.

The string literal `"Good Morning"` is stored in memory, and when you use it you are given a pointer to the first character.  Adding five to that value gives a pointer five characters into the string.

All that the `printf` function sees is a pointer `char const * fmt`, so you can give it anything you like...  But you do need to be sure that your program is allowed to use the memory at that address, and that it points to a null-terminated array of characters.

Answer (score 0):

`"Good Morning "` is a `const char*`. It is a pointer - a memory location - where this string is placed. "Good Morning " + 5 is a pointer to 5 places *after* this position. `+` symmetrical, so `"Good Morning " + 5` equals `5 + "Good Morning "`.

Comment: "is a `const char*`" -- in some other language, but in C it's `char*`.